# how can I add string and move figures in a separate folder

Tags: bash, macos, unix

I have many figures on a folder , they are all .png
I have a txt file like this too

```
label                    first      end     group
Afghanestan              200        201     1
Afghanestankabol         12         14      1
Afghanestankabolindia    17         10      1
indiaAfghanestan         10         2       2
Holandnorway             500        400     3
holand                   100        200     3
holandindia              400        300     3
USA                      10         20      4
USAargentina             12         1       4
USAargentinabrazil       16         15      4
```

`label` is the name of images , here what I am going to do

- I want to create as many folder as groups (in this case 4)
- Then add the **start** before the name and add the **end** at the end of the name of the image and move the to that folder they are assigned to

for example the image **Afghanestan**

the name of the image become 200A_fghanestan_201.png and it will be moved to folder 1

at the beginning I thought I should read the file line by line

```
#!/bin/sh
value=`myfile.txt`
echo "$label"
```

The output will look like this

4 folders. for example

```
user:outp admin$ ls
1   2   3   4
user:outp admin$ cd 1
user:1 admin$ ls
12_Afghanestankabol_14.png  200_Afghanestan_201.png
17_Afghanestankabolindia_10.png
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? With Bash? Python? Something else?
Show us your attempt.

Comment: @mattias I have tried so many things but none help me to move forward. so I asked it here. for example to read the file.txt, I use `cat`it does not show everything , I dont know how to create folders as many and groups etc etc

Comment: Huh? You have minus 100 images all called `holandindia`?

Comment: @Mark Setchell no I have 100 images but one is called  `holandindia`, another one called `holland`etc etc

Comment: Maybe you could add a few lines from the output from `ls` because your description is very poor...

Comment: @Mark Setchell please look above , I added an example

Comment: So, each line in your input file corresponds to a single image?

Comment: @Mark Setchell Yes, I am trying to group them into a folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the file below in your HOME directory as `go`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed '1d' myfile.txt | while read label first end group ; do
   echo mkdir -p ${group}
   echo mv ${label}.png ${group}/${first}_${label}_${end}.png
done
```

Then start Terminal and make the script executable with:

```
chmod +x $HOME/go
```

Then change directory to where your images are and run the script with:

```
cd path/to/your/images
$HOME/go
```

If you like what it does, remove the word `echo` from the middle two lines and it will actually do it.

---

**Explanation**

The first line of the script uses `sed` to delete the first line of your file because that is just header. Then it reads a line at a time into four variables, makes the output directory (using `-p` so there are no errors if the directory already exists) and moves the file to the appropriate place.

**Please make a backup copy of your files and run it on those first!**

Comment: what do you mean by `Save the file below in your HOME directory as go:` I cannot put them together for example in a desktop ?if no, should I only move the txt file into the home directory ? and how

Comment: You *can* save it as `go` on your Desktop (though saving scripts and images all over a desktop just makes a mess), but then you'll have to do `chmod +x $HOME/Desktop/go` and the last step will become `$HOME/Desktop/go`

Comment: I made a folder named my data , then I put everything there , then I did the following but nothing happened `user:mydata admin$ chmod +x /Users/admin/Desktop/mydata/go.sh` and then 
`user:mydata admin$ ./go.sh` The key.txt I open it with xls file and each one is in one column (column one is label, column 2 is the start , column 3 is the stop and last column is the group) , then save it again as txt. is this something to do with that ?

Comment: Your file is supposed to be a text file, not an Excel `.xls` file. Please load the text file containing the new names into `TextEdit` and click `Format` in the menu at the top-left of the screen and if it offers "Make plain text", click on that and re-save it and try again.

Comment: this is defiantly a .txt (tab delimited text ) , can you please let me know which txt editor do you use ? I use wrangler or sublime

Comment: `TextEdit`. Hit `command+space` and type "textedit" then hit "Enter" to start it.

Comment: I solved it. Thank you so much for your amazing help, I liked it and accepted it

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should present what you've tried, and then the community will assist with issues.  I'll give you a start:

```
  while read label first end group
    do
      mv ${label}.png /path/to/${group}/${first}_${label}_${last}.png
```

Comment: I have tried a lot with no uses, something that does not work, I did not mean to make people more confused so I prefer to ask question